# User fetching with Rails, BCrypt, Mongoid, and MongoLab fails in deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mongoid, mlab

I'm a first-time poster trying to wade through making MongoDB play nice with Rails and Heroku. Right now, I'm getting errors that make me think there is a problem comparing user passwords (that are supposed to be obscured with Bcrypt) during log in. **Eager for more advanced eyes, or a better idea of how to troubleshoot this problem.**

In the app, I find and create Users like so:

```
def create
 password_key = BCrypt::Password.create(params[:user][:password]) 
 params[:user][:password] = password_key 
 newUser = User.create(params[:user])

 flash[:message] = "Account created! Please log in:"

 redirect_to controller: "users", action: "login"
end

def login
end

def find
 username = params[:user][:username]
 @user = User.where( username: username )[0]

 if @user
  if BCrypt::Password.new(@user.password) == params[:user][:password] 
    session[:user_id] = @user.id 
    redirect_to controller: "application", action: "home"
  else
    flash[:message] = "Wrong password. Try again."
    redirect_to controller: "users", action: "login"
  end
 else
  flash[:message] = "We didn't recognize that username."
  redirect_to controller: "users", action: "login"
 end

end
```

This worked fine for me in local dev. When I first deployed to Heroku, I received a "Something went wrong." error instantly upon trying to create a new user, which indicated that I didn't have my production environment configured correctly.

After more reading, I decided to use MongoLab to host my production database. I set that up with an add-on to my heroku repository following [this tutorial.](http://marianalenetis.com/2013/08/deploy-ruby-on-rails-mongodb-projects-to-heroku/)

Then I set my heroku env. variable MONGOLAB_URI to the appropriate URI, and included the following in my **mongoid.yml** file:

```
production:
 sessions:
 default:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
  options:
    consistency: :strong
    safe: true
    skip_version_check: true
```

Now, when I access the live app, I no longer get an error when I try to create a user! I am redirected as I would expect and receive my "Account created! Please log in:" flash message.

**HOWEVEVER, when I try to login with the credentials I just saved to the database, I'm redirected and my "Wrong password. Try again." flash message fires** -- which to me indicates that there is some kind of issue with how passwords are being stored or compared with the combination of BCrypt/Mongoid/MongoLab.

Help, please! Is there something I'm missing about how to use BCrypt with Mongoid? This is only happening to me in production and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

Thanks in advance.